# Showing a list of all emotes in my discord server returns an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, discord, discord.js

I'm running a server and have a command that lists all emotes in the server via a bot, but it's giving me an error that a character limit is being hit.
I know why this issue is happening, I just don't really have a way to fix it.

```
    //lists all emotes of the current server
let emojiRegex = new RegExp('^' + prefix + '((emoji)|(emotes))$', 'gi');
if (emojiRegex.exec(msg)) {
    // if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "emotes" || msg.startsWith(prefix + "emoji"))) {
    const emojiList = message.guild.emojis.map(e => e.toString()).join(" ");
    message.channel.send(emojiList);
}
```

this appearently results in a message in above 2000 characters due to an emote in discord existing as emotename:emoteID or something along those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your message is just text (and thus not an Embed), you can use the [split option in MessageOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions) to split the text into acceptable chunks. By default this will split the text on any newline (\n) character but since you don't have that, we need to supply our own split character. Change your code to the following and it should work just fine:

```js
//lists all emotes of the current server
let emojiRegex = new RegExp('^' + prefix + '((emoji)|(emotes))$', 'gi');
if (emojiRegex.exec(msg)) {
    // if (msg.startsWith(prefix + "emotes" || msg.startsWith(prefix + "emoji"))) {
    const emojiList = message.guild.emojis.map(e => e.toString()).join(" ");

    // Split the message on a space since we know those are in the message
    // because of the .join function
    message.channel.send(emojiList, {split: {char: ' '}});
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I got an exception

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Message exceeds the max length and contains no split characters.`

Comment: Ah apologies, I've overlooked something. See the updated answer for (what should be) a fix for this

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way to avoid the 2000 character limit, all you will have to do is add the split parameter when sending the message, by doing it like this:

```js
let emojiRegex = new RegExp('^' + prefix + '((emoji)|(emotes))$', 'gi');
if (emojiRegex.exec(msg)) {
    const emojiList = message.guild.emojis.map(e => e.toString()).join(" ");
    message.channel.send(emojiList, { split: true }); // as you can see, we have added the split parameter here so every time it hits the character limit, it send's the first message then follow's it up with another message.
}
```

Hope this help's you!

Comment: I tried this, but I got the following exception for it

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Message exceeds the max length and contains no split characters.`


I npm installed lodash as well so that can't be the issue

Comment: hm, weird, i dont know how to fix it... i do have a example that sends all the emoji's in the guild, if you want to check it out, [here it is](https://gist.github.com/TheGamer456YT/36ca9a1ac1400eef4ec5a5506da5dc58). Other than that, i can't help you...